# Docker Compose command fails in VS CODE

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error when I use docker-compose up --force-recreate  --build
I have updated to VS Studio 2022 however am still using VS CODE. DOTNET --LISTS SDKS shows all my sdks... I have a lot of versions though should I remove all besides the 7? Is this a Docker issue - docker desktop shows its up to date.

Am I missing a step to get it to work with VS CODE? I'm not finding a lot of help on google searches besides 'updating to VS CODE 2022 resolved for me' .. well I did and VS CODE is my preferred editor. Am I stuck having to use Studio only??

```
error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either 
target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0. 
[/source/JPI.Express.Core/JPI.Express.Core.csproj]


ADDING the Docker file where I think the issue is. Should the aspnet:6.0 be 7.0 as well as the sdk:6.0-bullseye-slin be 7.0? 


    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE xx
    EXPOSE xxx
    # Patch security vulnerabilities with apt-get upgrade
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

    FROM base as vulnerabilityscan
    ARG failbuild=0
    COPY --from=aquasec/trivy:latest /usr/local/bin/trivy 
    /usr/local/bin/trivy
    RUN trivy filesystem --exit-code $failbuild --no-progress -- 
    severity CRITICAL --ignore-unfixed /
    RUN echo scancompleted > /scancompleted

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS build
    WORKDIR /
    COPY . .
```

Comment: What is the version of the .NET project you're attempting to build? Is it targeting .NET 7?